# How Do I Uninstall a Current WordPress Theme and Install a Fresh Theme

Tags: plugins, themes, uninstallation

I own a site called explainz.com. The current theme is all messed up. I am considering installing a new theme. How do I actually go about it? 
Would it be sufficient if I just uninstalled the existing theme and installed the new theme from my dashboard? Is there anything else I need to do so that there are no previous theme remnants. By the way, I would be individually uninstalling certain plugins as well. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You can install the new theme and preview how it would look before changing it.
See https://en.support.wordpress.com/themes/#preview-themes for more info.

Once you have tested that it works, you can then activate the new theme. I would keep the old theme for a few weeks until you're confident that there is nothing else needed, then take a backup of old theme before deleting it.

I'd also review the current theme's `functions.php` file for any customised code that you may want to copy in to the new theme's `functions.php` file or write a plugin to make it compatible across all themes.

As a final note though in case not obvious - install the new theme first before deleting the current/active theme.

Answer (score 0):

There is more ways to do it, like cpanel or ftp access, check out codex page https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Themes

Answer (score 0):

Themes are quite often depending on certain plugins, such as Custom Fields or Custom Post Type, to control and display the contents. If you install a different theme the chance is that it doesn't work the same way. Start inactivating modules one-by-one and see how/if the site works.

All theme files are located in the **wp-content/themes**-folder. If you remove it there should be no remnants, unless some bad practices are present:

- Hacks have been made to the WP core files to suit the theme
- Hacks have been made to the any plugin files to suit the theme
- Files in the media library have been used in the theme

You could always use the theme live preview function to test new themes without actually going live with it.